# VLOOKUP combined with MIN or MAX

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say I have a products A, B and C on Sheet1:

I want to vlookup product "A" on Sheet2 and analyse the range associated with it:

E.g. Sheet1

Can I have a formula which will vlookup A from Sheet1 on Sheet 2 and perform =MAX(B1:K1) (on the range associated with A on Sheet2). It would have to be a hybrid of vlookup and MAX of some sort I would imagine?

Thanks

Comment: No you would want a MAX(IF()) type formula.  Vlookup only returns the first not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly `=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet2!$B:$K/(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$15=A1),1)`

Great thanks to Scott Craner